# Dynamic content loading in Expander, WPF

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, dynamic-data, expander, wpf-4.0

I've a json file having a list of data.
 For eg

```
    {
    "data" : 
        { 
            "Name" : "Abc",
            "Desc" : "123"
        },
        { 
            "Name" : "Def",
            "Desc" : "456"
        }, 
        { 
            "Name" : "Ghi",
            "Desc" : "789"
        }
  }
```

So, what I need is a WPF application that would show a list of expanders with headers as Name as stated in Json and it's content as Desc.

Everything should be dynamically loaded. 
Also, initially only the names should be loaded onto expander's headers and all unexpanded. Only when user expands one of them, it should load that particular expander's description and display accordingly.

The last part is important as my json file is in MBs and performance is a real issue.

I'm able to parse all json and create dynamic list of expanders, but didn't find any approach for loading expander's content at run time.

I've tried this approach :

https://wpf.2000things.com/2013/09/26/915-delaying-generation-of-expander-content/

But I can't access the textblock using its name. Also, their names would coincide with other expanders, and I can't hard code them.

Comment: Post your code please. WPF controls are rendered based on their data bindings, so all of them are dynamic in one way or another. The article you linked to is a bad example as it ignores data bindings and tries to modify the UI directly, as if this was a Winforms application

Comment: You *don't* need an Expander to display only a limited amount of data at a time anyway. Most elements support data and/or scrolling virtualization. This means they will only pull what data they need to display for each screen. You can't display 1000 expanders any more than you can display 1000 text boxes after all

Comment: Why not just use a ListView with the template you want? Check [Displaying Large Data Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-controls#Displaying) in the docs. It explains how UI virtualization works and mentions it's enabled by default in ListView elements

Comment: Ah, thanks. Scrolling virtualization was exactly what I needed. I'm was using a listview now, populated by expanders and wanted to load it's content, when expanded through the function. Virtualization made it a lot easier lol. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, you could add an answer and will tick that right, if you're looking for points :3 Or i'll just delete this post.